# DJANGO: template gets rendered on local server but doesn't get rendered on the live server

Tags: django, sendgrid

For my site, the template that i have gets rendered before sending the mail but doesn't render on the live server and it just send me the empty template:

my settings.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']

SEND_BROKEN_LINK_EMAILS = True

SERVER_EMAIL = 'my email'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.zoho.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_smtp_ssl.SSLEmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my email'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'my email'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my pass'


SENDGRID_EMAIL_PORT = 587
SENDGRID_EMAIL_USERNAME = 'sendgrid credential username'
SENDGRID_EMAIL_PASSWORD = 'sendgrid credential pass'
SENDGRID_API_KEY = 'my key'
```

my sendEmail.py:

```
def send_contact_email(subject, template_path, dynamic_content,  from_email,from_name, destination_email, destination_name):

html = get_template(template_path)
d = Context(dynamic_content)
content = html._render(d)
print(dynamic_content)

client = sendgrid.SendGridClient(settings.SENDGRID_API_KEY)


mail = Mail(
    subject = subject,
    body="Automated mail from lokafy",
    from_email=from_name + " " + "<" + from_email + ">",
    to=[destination_email],
    html=content,
    fail_silently=False,
)
client.send(mail)
```

and my template: contact-from.html:

`<p>Phone number: {{ phone }}</p>
<br>
<p>Message from user: {{ message }}</p>`

Comment: First of all change ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost'] to ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] in production

Comment: hey, what would that do? (sorry new to django), btw that still doesn't work

Comment: To serve others than localhost which in production is the server your are hosting your webapp in, more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Comment: okay makes sense, but the email that i receive through the code above (with ALLOWED_HOSTS =['*']), has not been rendered.
this is on live site, on local i receive and email that is rendered with the dynamic_content, but on live site its not rendered

Comment: The only other thing that I see isn't right in your code is: html._render(d) which should be html.render(d)

Comment: i realized that and i changed that. but still not working for some reason